# update another table when updated mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have 2 tables, students and Math. I want to UPDATE existing data on Math.Last_name when I update the students.Last_Name using the ID I am updating in students.

Students table

```
CREATE TABLE `STUDENTS` (
`Date_Modified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`LRN` BIGINT(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Last_Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`First_Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`LRN`)
)COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=123456789112;
```

MATH TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE `Math` (
`Date_Modified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`LRN` BIGINT(12) NOT NULL,
`Last_Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`First_Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`Level` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
`UT1` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
`Q1` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`UT2` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`Q2` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`UT3` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`Q3` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`UT4` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`Q4` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`FINAL GRADE` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`LRN`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

MY TRIGGER

```
CREATE TRIGGER `STUDENTS_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `STUDENTS` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE Math
SET Last_Name = NEW.Last_Name
WHERE LRN IN (SELECT LRN FROM Math where LRN = NEW.LRN);
END
```

Comment: Please share the DDL of both tables and some sample data what it would look like after the update happens on `students` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a sub select in the update command, since for each row it will pick up the new LRN value and will update all of them in the `MATH` table where the `new.LRN` matches in the `MATH` table. Here how the trigger would look like

```
delimiter //
create trigger `STUDENTS_after_update` after update on `STUDENTS`
for each row
begin
 update Math
 set Last_Name = NEW.Last_Name
 where LRN = NEW.LRN ;
end;//

delimiter ;
```

Note that I have added delimiter which is needed when you run them in the Mysql CLI, some other user interface like PHPMyadmin you need to select the delimiter from the user interface.

Comment: I've been doing this already however, it works now. Before, it gives me "subquery returns more than 1 row". Anyways, thanks!

Comment: Yes you do not need to provide a subselect in to the update part.